# how to put a thread in Wait in Android

Tags: android

I have a thread running in my program When Mouse-down Event generates I want to put that thread in wait() and in Mouse-up I want to Notify that thread

But when I tried to do this It is giving me error like "Object not locked by Thread" so can anyone help me how to solve this..

Comment: Did you put sync-object into synchronized block ?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Thread.sleep()` and then `Thread.interrupt()` to wake it up.

something like this:

```
Thread t;

startThread() {
  t = new Thread() {
    public void run () {
       doThings();
       sleep(10000);
    }
  }

  t.start();
}

interruptThread() {
  if (t != null) t.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't stop the UI Thread (this is the Thread that called the event). This Thread is used to dispatch UI events and if you could make it wait() it'll render your UI unresponsive.

You'll have to create your own Thread.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, calling wait() on a thread causes a crash... i dont know if there is a safe way to pause a thread (or at least an easy way)